# Azure API app strange delay before send response

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I'm experiencing a really strange problem.

My API is taking a long time to response and I can't see why from AppInsights.

Attached is the end-to-end transaction view. It shows that the API call took 16.7 seconds. It's clear that a dependency call took 3.8 seconds. Some DB operation took several ms. But what's causing the long delay? What happened in the red rectangle marked with question mark?

The web app is hosted with a P1V2 app service plan. The plan is shared by 3 API apps. Could this be a problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The web app is hosted with a P1V2 app service plan. The plan is shared by 3 API apps. Could this be a problem?**

**No**, that couldn't be the problem because the P1V2 app service plan is a premium service plan. We can reduce the cost consumption by combining multiple apps into a single app service plan. We can add multiple apps to an existing plan as long as the [plan](https://www.azure.cn/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) has enough resources.

**Here are my few observations.**

1. The P1-V2 service plan will have 3.5 GB of RAM and 1 VCore processor. We need to cross-check the utilization logs once.
2. APIs are calling token methods Get/msi/token, and there onwards it's forward to the **PUT call on the portal; there it's taking close to 16 seconds.**
   [image]
3. The one mentioned in the red box is not an issue because it **takes only 16 milliseconds to execute SQL.**

Comment: The red bar marked with question mark isn't about that DB call. It's a question of what happened in that period of time? I can't see anything in the end-to-end transaction.

Comment: And yes the question is indeed about that PUT call.